# Why is this excel concatenation not working?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to do this excel formula if something is true then concatenate the following cells:

```
=IF(O7>0,concatenate=(H7,J7,K7,L7,M7,N7),H7)
```

however I keep getting a #NAME! error.

I have tried:

```
=IF(O7>0,(concatenate=(H7,J7,K7,L7,M7,N7)),H7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without the `=` after [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d):

```
=IF(O7>0,CONCATENATE(H7,J7,K7,L7,M7,N7),H7)
```

Answer (score 0):

`concatenate=` is not an Excel function, you need to do it *without* the `=`.

Comment: @Vivian, the *usual* behaviour is to upvote all answers that helped and accept one of them (probably Anderson's in this case since it contains slightly more detail than mine).